# Prove that any complex matrix can be expressed in term of Hermitian and anti-Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

How can we prove that any complex matrix can be expressed in term of hermitian and anti-hermitian matrices of the following form
$A = H_1 + iH_2$
Where, $H_1$ is hermitian and $H_2$ is an anti-hermitian matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the unique decomposition
$$ A = \frac{A+A^*}{2} + i\frac{A-A^*}{2i} =: H_1 + iH_2. $$
Then
$$ H_1^* = \left(\frac{A+A^*}{2}\right)^* = \frac{A^*+A}{2} = H_1 $$
is Hermitian, and
$$ H_2^* = \left(\frac{A-A^*}{2i}\right)^* = \frac{A^*-A}{2(-i)} = H_2, $$
is also Hermitian (and so $iH_2$ is antiHermitian, as it must be: if $H_2$ was antiHermitian, $iH_2$ would be Hermitian).

Comment: One might want to call $H_1 =: \operatorname{Re}(A)$ and $H_2 =: \operatorname{Im}(A)$.